# Creating a timer in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an exercise skill for Alexa in Python 2.7. 
I want Alexa to start a 10 second timer and say "Exercise". Once the 10 seconds is over Alexa should say "Stop".

I have tried doing this using the *break* SSML tag:

```
<speak>Exercise! <break time="10s"/> Stop </speak>
```

However this starts a timer/pause after "Exercise" has been said, I require the "Exercise" dictation to be inclusive of the 10 second timer. 
Any ideas how I could implement this?

Comment: <speak>Exercise! <break time="9s"/> Stop </speak> is the only choice.

Comment: What is your goal? You could use Reminders API to set a reminder in 10 seconds from now in order to notify user, that time is over. Do you expect any interaction after this time?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot run the lambda for more than the defined time limit.